# How to check for and replace non UTF-8 characters in tcl?

Tags: regex, tcl, utf

What's the best way to search if a given string contains non UTF-8 characters in tcl? Is regexp'ing `"^[\x00-\x7f]+$"` the only way forward?

I'm trying to write a tcl proc to check if a given variable contains non UTF-8 characters and if it does replace it with "Not supported"

Answer (score 3):

All Tcl's characters are Unicode characters.

OK, that's not helpful. You *actually* appear to be asking about non-ASCII characters. Supposing you wanted to replace each non-ASCII character with a `?`, you might use a regular expression substitution, like this:

```
regsub -all {[\u0080-\uffff]} $inputString "?" outputString
```

The key here is that the RE is in braces (virtually always ***strongly recommended***) and that we're using `\uXXXX` escape sequences (which the RE engine also understands). That'll put many `?`s in potentially, but I'm sure you can adjust.